# Elevation to earth curvature mapping in MatLab

Tags: matlab

In MatLab I've got elevetion of terrain in vector. All of these values are meters above sea level. I have got latitude and longitude of transmitter and receiver too. I know the resolution of elevation vector (path distance / vector elements). Has anybody idea, how to "put" these points to curvature of Earth? Now I've got something like that:

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/dexpqw.jpg]

And this is what i want to have:

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/2uj147k.png]

By red lines I mark heights which are saved in vector. I have no idea, how i can map this vector for curvature of Earth. Anybody has some? I don't really want to get working code, but only some tips how bite this problem.

On the second picture red lines aren't normal, beacuse it is MS Paint. And yes, they should be normal. In case of adding, I have only higher points in this location, but there should be included Earth radius.

So, I can use geoidheight function, and add to this my height. But now I have some problem to visualize it on plot. Any ides?

Comment: I am a little confused, Why aren't the red lines (height) normal to the curve of the earth (black line)? Are you trying to get the blue line to bend with the curve the earth? If so, just use addition, and know that the yscale will be off. It sounds like you will have to make your own scale no matter what your approach is if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I disagree, here is why: Are you trying to get ... If so, just use addition, and know that the yscale will be off.  (my answer is addition, and that the yscale will be off) Thanks for looking out though :)

Comment: OK, in first post I explain red lines, and how i can not simply add it

Comment: My answer suggesting using geoid may have been overkill.   Since your measurements are above mean sea level, and mean sea level follows   the curvature of the earth, wouldn't the "curvature" of the earth be a flat line when plotted against your measurements?   If you care about localized deviations from mean sea level, geoid would be useful, but do you care?

Comment: Sooo the real question here is how to get the black line?

Comment: @kruchx What does the X axis on your plot represent?